# Will Apple reject my app if i use VOIP Capability in chat app(WhatsApp like application)

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, xmpp, voip

We are developing a chat application like WhatsApp. It's XMPP based application, the XMPP complaint servers are follows push model for sending the messages, presence..etc.

So when user is offline the messages goes into offline stack and pushes again once user comes into online.

We want know that when app is killed , Can we use voip capabilities to run in background? or we really need go push notification model?

Please help Me .

Comment: For absolute clarification, couldn't you send an email to the Apple Developer support?

Comment: You can add PushKit voip push notification support, and as long as you also add VoiP call feature, your app will be approved.
See Q&A here for details ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625687/apple-rejection-after-implementing-silent-notifictaions-with-pushkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add VOIP for chat application but there are other background task execution options by which you can achieve this. 
Modify your server side piece send notifications to the app at reasonable time intervals if user if not online and your app will get opportunity to execute in background when these notifications are delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Apple will reject your app if you use VOIP Capability in chat app(WhatsApp like application)
if are you trying to use in background with help of VOIP but you primary not implemented VOIP functionality then apple will reject your app i tried before this for my streaming music player.