# Apple rejection after implementing silent notifications with PushKit

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We added silent notifications which require PushKit and enabling VoIP in the Info.plist

See [Apple's PushKit Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html)

Now my app is rejected by Apple:

> Your app declares support for VoIP in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but does not include any Voice over IP services.
>   Please revise your app to either add VoIP features or remove the "voip" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

1. The app is NOT a VoIP therefore it doesn't require VoIP features.
2. Removing the VoIP from `UIBackgroundModes` causes the silent notifications to stop working.

Anyone know what I should do?

What VoIP feature can I add (even if I dont use it, just to pass the review)?

I asked Apple but they got back with an auto generated response with the same rejection reason.

Comment: You don't need to use PushKit or the VoIP background mode to use silent notifications.

Comment: To clarify @dan's comment; you can use silent notifications with the old push notification methods. The difference is if your app is terminated then your app won't be relaunched to receive the notification as it is with Pushkit. Pushkit can only be used by VoIP apps, so if your app isn't VoIP then you can't use Pushkit

Comment: Thank you Dan and Paul for you comments!   Here's why we need PushKit. Our notification playloads are encrypted. In order to show the notification once the user has swipped the app closed, PushKit wakes up the app, the app decrypts the message and we then popup the notification.  
We are not a VoIP app but still rely on PushKit for its abilities for bg processing.

Answer (score 4):

You should likely be using iOS Service Extensions to decrypt the message.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

> You use this extension to modify the notification’s content or download content related to the extension. For example, you could use the extension to decrypt an encrypted data block or to download images associated with the notification.

You can also learn more about how this works at this WWDC talk.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/

Implementing VoIP features to do this is complete overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Update on the resolution -

1. We installed a third party VoIP solution and implemented VoIP calls in our app. Awkward to be forced to add a feature but in our case it was right for our app.
2. In iTunesConnect submission page, under "App Review Information" "Notes" I had to state that we added a new feature VoIP calls, with steps to test VoIP calls.
   This caught the reviewers attention to the new VoIP call feature and the app passed.

When I added the new feature under "whats new in this version", the app continued to get rejected.

Answer (score 1):

We have also faced same issue -

- You can't use voip background mode unless you implement voip
  features.
- Just implement `IM(chat)` feature in your app then you will be capable to publish your
  app at Appstore.

Good luck!